# Why is the value for TextBox.Background ignored when IsReadOnly is set to true?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a TextBox control. When I set the IsReadOnly property to True, the value I specify for the Background property is ignored. When IsReadOnly is set to False, the value I specify for the Background property is used.

Does anyone know why the Background property is ignored when the IsReadOnly property is set to True?

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt" 
  Grid.Row="0" 
  Grid.Column="1" 
  Margin="10 2" 
  IsReadOnly="True" 
  Background="#538DD5" 
  FontWeight="Bold" 
  Text="0"  
  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Do you have any styles that get applied to all `TextBox` controls?

Comment: No, I do not have styles applied to the TextBox, only a DataGrid that is in another Grid

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happened due to another reason, `IsReadOnly` gets or sets a value that indicates whether the text editing `control` is read-only to a user. It returns `true` if the contents of the `text` editing `control` are read-only to a user; otherwise, the contents of the text editing control can be modified by the user. The default value is `false`.

Comment: No, I want the user to only view information and not edit it, so the value should be True IsReadOnly

Comment: I get same background both for IsReadOnly="True"  and IsReadOnly="False".@Richard

Comment: It is very strange :/

Comment: You can try textblock in place of textbox.

Comment: TextBlock has no property IsReadOnly

Comment: That's true, I will try